# What is the difference between System.err and java.lang.Error

Tags: java, error-handling

I am a newbie in java. I am trying to implement a meeting room booking system with java. I want to print out all the error information to the prompt.

After searching, I find both `System.err.println("error 101")` and `java.lang.Error("error 101")` can create an error and output it.

Therefore, my questions are (1)What is the difference between them? (2)Which one is more effective when implementing a system?

Comment: These are completely different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two have nothing to do with one another.

> (1)What is the difference between them?

[`System.err`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err) is a `PrintStream` you can write to that will be output to the standard error stream of the console, for apps running in a console.

[`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is an error class, which is a `Throwable` for serious errors that the program probably can't recover from.

> (2)Which one is more effective when implementing a system?

"More effective" is a very vague term.

In the normal course of things, you might output error messages to `System.err` **if** your program is a command-line program. You are unlikely to directly throw `Error` or subclass it; instead, for *exceptional* conditions, you're likely to use one of the `Exception` classes and/or derive your own.

I suggest reading through the documentation linked above, and also the [Java Exceptions Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more about exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My meeting room booking system is a command-line program. You mean I just need to output error messages by using `System.err`? Do you think I need to create a error class that store all kinds of error messages?

Comment: @allenwang: That's totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thats to different things.

`System.err.println` print a message to the error stream.

`java.lang.Error`

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

Is like an Exception wich not should be catched.

So these thinks can not be used in the same context.